# OpenCV detecting drilled holes

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a project where I have to detect drilled holes on a surface. (the top two holes and there for orientation purposes only)

[image: Image: surface to scan sample 1]
[image: Image: surface to scan sample 2]

After detecting the holes the pattern will judge the placement of the holes and give results. I have created an overlay grid layout and placed it over the camera2api preview so the user can align the holes and scan (The real testing will not be of a picture from the LCD as shown in the screenshot)

[image]

Currently, I'm cropping the image based on the grid and resizing it to 1920x2560 to have a consistent frame for pattern judgement, which makes a single grid of roughly about 300px. I am unable to detect the blobs can someone suggest what sort of filtering I should choose for this work and if there is a better approach for doing this rather than using a grid layout as the placement of the holes in regard to the orientation holes matter for final results (both x and y axis)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Mat srcMat = resizeAndCropMatToGrid(mats[0]);
        if (srcMat == null) {
            exception = new Exception("Cropping Failed");
            errorMessage = "Unable to crop image based on grid";
            return null;
        }
        matProgressTask = srcMat;
        Mat processedMat = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, processedMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(processedMat, processedMat, new org.opencv.core.Size(5, 5), 5);
    Imgproc.threshold(processedMat, processedMat, 115, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);


        matProgressTask = processedMat;


        FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIMPLEBLOB);
        featureDetector.read(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/blob.xml");
        MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        featureDetector.detect(processedMat, matOfKeyPoint);
        KeyPoint[] keyPointsArray = matOfKeyPoint.toArray();
        Log.e("keypoints", "" + Arrays.toString(keyPointsArray));
            if (keyPointsArray.length < 1) {
            exception = new Exception("Blobs Missing");
            errorMessage = "Error: Unable to filter blobs";
        } else {
            try {
                MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPointFilteredBlobs = new MatOfKeyPoint(keyPointsArray);
                Features2d.drawKeypoints(srcMat, matOfKeyPointFilteredBlobs, srcMat, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), Features2d.DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                exception = e;
                errorMessage = "Error: Unable to draw Blobs";
                return null;
            }
            matProgressTask = srcMat;
            onProgressUpdate();
            patterData = pinpointBlobsToGetData(keyPointsArray);
            if (patterData == null) {
                exception = new Exception("Unable to establish pattern");
                errorMessage = "Error: Key points array is null";
            }
        }
```

And here is the blobby file configuration that I'm using:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<format>3</format>
<thresholdStep>10.</thresholdStep>
<minThreshold>50.</minThreshold>
<maxThreshold>120.</maxThreshold>
<minRepeatability>2</minRepeatability>
<minDistBetweenBlobs>20.</minDistBetweenBlobs>
<filterByColor>1</filterByColor>
<blobColor>0</blobColor>
<filterByArea>1</filterByArea>
<minArea>2300.</minArea>
<maxArea>4500.</maxArea>
<filterByCircularity>1</filterByCircularity>
<minCircularity>0.2</minCircularity>
<maxCircularity>1.0</maxCircularity>
<filterByInertia>1</filterByInertia>
<minInertiaRatio>0.2</minInertiaRatio>
<maxInertiaRatio>1.0</maxInertiaRatio>
<filterByConvexity>1</filterByConvexity>
<minConvexity>0.2</minConvexity>
<maxConvexity>1.0</maxConvexity>
</opencv_storage>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try [Hough Circle Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html).

Comment: The first thing you do is threshold, but that should really be the last thing. The grey-value image has a lot of information that you throw away. It is a lot easier to detect these holes if you don’t immediately binarize. Also, you use a fixed threshold. That is a bad idea, as the illumination can change, or the surface reflectivity can change, changing what the ideal threshold would be.

Comment: from.your threshold image I would findContours, use minimumBoumdingCircle and compare the redult with the acutual contour, how much it differs from the actual contour and either accept or decline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have managed to figure it by passing the mat directly to FeatureDetector class without any prior processing...

```
            Mat srcMat = mats[0];
        if (srcMat == null) {
            exception = new Exception("Cropping Failed");
            errorMessage = "Unable to crop image based on grid";
            return null;
        }
        matProgressTask = srcMat;

        FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIMPLEBLOB);
        featureDetector.read(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/blob.xml");
        Log.e("LoadingBlob", "wqfqfwq");
        MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        featureDetector.detect(srcMat, matOfKeyPoint);
        KeyPoint[] keyPointsArray = matOfKeyPoint.toArray();
        Log.e("keypoints", "" + Arrays.toString(keyPointsArray));
            if (keyPointsArray.length < 1) {
            exception = new Exception("Blobs Missing");
            errorMessage = "Error: Unable to filter blobs";
        } else {
            try {
                MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPointFilteredBlobs = new MatOfKeyPoint(keyPointsArray);
                Features2d.drawKeypoints(srcMat, matOfKeyPointFilteredBlobs, srcMat, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), Features2d.DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                exception = e;
                errorMessage = "Error: Unable to draw Blobs";
                return null;
            }
            matProgressTask = srcMat;
            onProgressUpdate();
            patterData = pinpointBlobsToGetData(keyPointsArray);
            if (patterData == null) {
                exception = new Exception("Unable to establish pattern");
                errorMessage = "Error: Key points array is null";
            }
        }
```

And my feature detector parameters file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<format>3</format>
<thresholdStep>10.</thresholdStep>
<minThreshold>50.</minThreshold>
<maxThreshold>120.</maxThreshold>
<minRepeatability>2</minRepeatability>
<minDistBetweenBlobs>20.</minDistBetweenBlobs>
<filterByColor>0</filterByColor>
<blobColor>0</blobColor>
<filterByArea>1</filterByArea>
<minArea>3000.</minArea>
<maxArea>10000.</maxArea>
<filterByCircularity>1</filterByCircularity>
<minCircularity>0.3</minCircularity>
<maxCircularity>1.0</maxCircularity>
<filterByInertia>1</filterByInertia>
<minInertiaRatio>0.3</minInertiaRatio>
<maxInertiaRatio>1.0</maxInertiaRatio>
<filterByConvexity>1</filterByConvexity>
<minConvexity>0.3</minConvexity>
<maxConvexity>1.0</maxConvexity>
</opencv_storage>
```

The result images: 
[image: Result Image 1]

[image: Result Image 2]

Answer (score 2):

**I am using Python.**

For the second image you provided I successfully detected the holes...

[image: res1]

...using this code...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Link\\Desktop\\2.jpg")
# cv2.imshow("original", img)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 31)
# cv2.imshow("blur", blur)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)

canny = cv2.Canny(thresh, 75, 200)
# cv2.imshow('canny', canny)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

contour_list = []
for contour in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if 5000 < area < 15000:
        contour_list.append(contour)

msg = "Total holes: {}".format(len(approx)//2)
cv2.putText(img, msg, (20, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.drawContours(img, contour_list, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('Objects Detected', img)

cv2.imwrite("detected_holes.png", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now, the first is a bit different. The same code will not work in detecting the right amount of holes. The program keep detecting also what is clearly not a hole (crack in left bottom angle..) with missing some main holes.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

[image: res2]

Not only the counter in that case is wrong but also, the main problem, is that the hole at right bottom can't be detected.

Comment: You are applying Canny to a binary image. All of the cleverness of the Canny method is wasted if you give it a binary image. Might as well simply do `dilation(thresh)-thresh`, which would be a lot faster. But then, why not directly find the contours of `thresh`? What is the point of finding edges first?

Comment: @CrisLuengo well, thats what I tried/achieved. Can you please provide some code with a different approach so we can see the solution you propose ? It would be useful to all...

Comment: Fair. This is not an easy problem, I don’t have any suggestions for how to solve it. I was just trying to point out that Canny is most useful (only useful?) on a gray-value image, and that you can remove that call here altogether and get the contours from `thresh` directly. When I comment with things like this, my aim is to teach what I know, not to belittle anyone. Sorry if I come across a bit harsh at times, a small text box online tends to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response, https://ibin.co/49adZ2LfQncR.png this is what I have achieved now, I think going with contours is a bad idea (maybe) as it is not detecting the top circle and drawing a contour out towards the boundry. Maybe there is another way specifically for detecting holes?